# How to handle files in an OOP way?

Tags: php, oop, symfony, symfony-2.1

I need to copy, move, and delete files.

Are there any components or classes for this?

I found this but it only moves: http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html

Or maybe I should stick to the native functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to Symfony framework you can look at [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.html)

The link you posted is a class in HttpFoundation used for uploaded files only.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has many function to deal with the filesystem.

- The [`copy()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) does as it's name implies - copies files
- The [`rename()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) actually renames and/or moves files.  This behavior will be familiar to linux users as the `mv` command.
- The [`unlink()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) is used to remove files.

[PHP's documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) has an entire section of features dedicated to file system manipulation.

---

The object oriented approach would come into  play when and how you implement these functions into your code.

Comment: @shi - I agree.  Capital letters must be placed where needed :P  Thanks for the edit ;)

Comment: Sure but that's not OOP, and I'm not sure if I should use it in a Symfony2 project. Eg: you can execute commands with exec(), but then you realize there is a better way for doing that in Symfony.

Comment: This is how any PHP code (in the end) will manipulate files.   It's the wrappers and how you use it that make it object oriented.  It's up to you! :)

Comment: Look I don't mean to argue, but if there already is a wrapper to improve all this (eg: throw exceptions instead of warning/fatal errors), I would like to know. I know it's only another layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could start your own helper class for wrapping the procedural commands?  Alternatively, you might look through some of the popular frameworks for a file system helper class, or similar.

```
class File {

    public static function exists($file) {
        return file_exists($file);
    }

    public static function copy($file, $destination) {
        // checks
        return copy($file, $destination);
        // error handling
    }

    public static function move($file, $destination) {
        return rename($file, $destination);
    }

    public static function delete($file) {
        return unlink($file);
    }
}

File::copy( 'test.txt', 'copy.txt' );
```